# turnaround time calculation in oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate turnaround time in days between 2 dates for each record.

- the first date (ORDERDATE), which is a string that I converted to date format
  using To_char(to_date) function
- the second date is (CURRENT_DATE) which has proper date format.

```
    SELECT 
         SPECCODE, 
         SOURCECODE, 
         SOURCEDESCRIPTION, 
         **TO_CHAR( TO_DATE (PATCASE.ORDEREDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))"ORDER_DATE",
         CURRENT_DATE**
    FROM  ...........
```

Comment: Do you want the number of days rounded off, rounded down, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use simple substraction:

```
SELECT
   TRUNC(TO_DATE (PATCASE.ORDEREDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') - SYSDATE) AS days_diff
FROM  ...;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a280f28a3a57d9163ead34a54553d24e)**

Comment: Thank you very much. It works except I needed to reverse the order for the subtraction as 

TRUNC(SYSDATE - TO_DATE (PATCASE.ORDEREDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') ) AS days_diff